# How to prevent an SSD from disappearing from BIOS

Tags: ssd, bios

I've only recently upgraded my old machine to a new one with a brand new 60gb SSD as my boot drive and a 1TB main drive.

Paranoid about completely breaking my SSD, I read up on a lot of issues that I needed to watch out for, including making sure AHCI was turned on and trim enabled.

PC has been working fine for a few weeks now, until today. My wife was watching some TV on the machine when it started to act strange and eventually blue screened.

She rebooted and the boot mgr was missing. When I got home from work I checked the BIOS and the drive had disappeared. I panicked and looked up some possible fixes, and I discovered a large amount of people having problems with the drive firmware, especially on OCZ Vertex and Agility drives, and my drive is an Agility 3 drive.

The problems included blue screens followed by missing drives, and a solution was to reset the CMOS and try again. This worked, and now everything seems to be working fine.

My question is, is there any way to prevent this from happening? Am I missing a setting for my SSD? All of the posts I found were from early to mid-2011 nothing for the end of 2011 to 2012. So I am wondering if I've missed anything.

EDIT: Checked my drives firmware and it is 2.15, which has had issues reported by users.

Comment: What lead you to believe the cause was when you did your research?

Comment: the symptoms matched and the solution was the same. Shortly before the blue screen apps crashes, the windows bar disapeared abd the icons on the desktop disapeared. Resetting the cmos fixed the issue. that's what lead me to believe it.

Comment: If people are having problems with the firmware, the manufacturer should have a newer firmware floating around somewhere.

Comment: Find another pc, make an image of the ssd, and upgrade your firmware [here](http://www.ocztechnology.com/ssd_tools/SandForce_Based/).  Make loads of backups.

Answer (score 1):

Have had the same problem and done the usual update firmware / BIOS etc. What worked was fitting the drive upside down, peeling off the large label and fitting a small heatsink (one from the North Bridge of a broken Gigabyte motherboard) using thermal paste and keeping in place with plastic tie-wraps.

Comment: Thats a new one. How did you know it was overheating?

Answer (score 0):

If the controller on a disk drive is not responding when the BIOS talks to it, there is little you can do on PC side unless you have engineering/insider information about the drive and can issue debug or similar commands to it - which likely require JTAG and electronics experience.

You are at an even worse situation with SSDs than with HDDs as the controller and flash are usuall on the same PCB.  So no board swapping.

You may try downgrading the firmware to an earlier stable version if it is possible.  If the firmware update utility runs through DOS you may get somewhere.  (I've never owned an SSD so I don't know how the firmware updates work - many CD-ROM firmware update utilities were done through DOS back in the day...)

Answer (score 0):

As well as checking the drive's firmware, also check your motherboard's. There have been a number of issues caused by interactions between some motherboard chipsets and SSD drives, which have been resolved through motherboard firmware updates as well as drive controller ones.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least in Windows 7 set drives to "never" turn off in power management. Make sure your ssd is in the 0 or 1 sata connection cluster at the mobo.

Everywhere I've read it's about firmware, firmware, firmware! Current version is 2.22 for your drive. If it's still under warranty return it and get a new one. Next time buy a good brand such as Samsung, Corsair or Crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions to this bug may vary, here is my story:

Had the same problem, I had a server that was working well for 1 year. Suddenly the ssd became erratic, appearing and disappearing from BIOS/Windows 7 at times.

Remember, this is a server so once I had it up and running, I did not touch it anymore. It was working 24/7 and bam, suddenly hit this bug.

So I worked my way up, did some experimentation and first switched the sata cable to a new one. Bingo, SSD can now be seen every time, no more disappearing. Didn't even need to do any firmware updates. Just plain old sata cable that came with motherboard died on me. This shows how poor quality the SATA cables are that come along with the motherboard.

**Solution : First try swapping current SSD SATA cable to a new higher quality SATA cable. If that fails than proceed to update the SSD firmware.**